# Sorting nested dictionary in python by value

Tags: python

This is my Dictionary:

```
 {{'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 1526815239}, 

 {'count': 10, 'leftCount': 10, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 1526814198}, 

 {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 1526815326}, 

 {'count': 8, 'leftCount': 8, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 1526815326},

 {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '30', 'submittedTime': 1526815239}}
```

I want to sort it by the value of the key="submittedTime". I have no idea how to make it work.

I tried lambda but I think I'm doing something wrong because the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted (asterisk, footnote, not *generally*)… Use a `list`, since your keys don't seem to have much significance in the first place.

Comment: You have to be clear about what your data looks like. You started with a dicrtionary, attempted to convert to a list, and now it looks like a set, not a dictionary. Also what do you think the result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes):

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

d = {0: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 
  1526815239}, 
 1: {'count': 10, 'leftCount': 10, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 
 1526814198}, 
 2: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 
 1526815326}, 
 3: {'count': 8, 'leftCount': 8, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 
 1526815326},
 4: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '30', 'submittedTime': 
 1526815239}}

print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]['submittedTime'])))
#OrderedDict([(1, {'count': 10, 'leftCount': 10, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 1526814198}), (0, {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 1526815239}), (4, {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '30', 'submittedTime': 1526815239}), (2, {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 1526815326}), (3, {'count': 8, 'leftCount': 8, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 1526815326})])
```

Answer (score 1):

try using lambda

```
d = {0: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 
1526815239},
1: {'count': 10, 'leftCount': 10, 'length': '5', 'submittedTime': 
1526814198},
2: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 
1526815326},
3: {'count': 8, 'leftCount': 8, 'length': '25', 'submittedTime': 
1526815326},
4: {'count': 5, 'leftCount': 5, 'length': '30', 'submittedTime': 
1526815239}}
dd = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]['submittedTime'])
```